# Adding permission management module for customization

Tags: abp

I have abp .Net Core Application and I have added permission module using command

```
abp add-module Volo.PermissionManagement --with-source-code --add-to-solution-file
```

then when I open application then found permission module added in solution under modules folder and solution build success but when I run application I get error in browser

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start
```

and error in log is

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.Application.Contracts, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.Application.Contracts, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, RuntimeType type, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, RuntimeType type, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo element, Boolean inherit)
   at Volo.Abp.Modularity.AbpModuleHelper.FindDependedModuleTypes(Type moduleType)
   at Volo.Abp.Modularity.AbpModuleHelper.AddModuleAndDependenciesRecursively(List`1 moduleTypes, Type moduleType, ILogger logger, Int32 depth)
   at Volo.Abp.Modularity.AbpModuleHelper.AddModuleAndDependenciesRecursively(List`1 moduleTypes, Type moduleType, ILogger logger, Int32 depth)
   at Volo.Abp.Modularity.AbpModuleHelper.AddModuleAndDependenciesRecursively(List`1 moduleTypes, Type moduleType, ILogger logger, Int32 depth)
   at Volo.Abp.Modularity.AbpModuleHelper.AddModuleAndDependenciesRecursively(List`1 moduleTypes, Type moduleType, ILogger logger, Int32 depth)
   at Volo.Abp.Modularity.AbpModuleHelper.FindAllModuleTypes(Type startupModuleType, ILogger logger)
   at Volo.Abp.Modularity.ModuleLoader.FillModules(List`1 modules, IServiceCollection services, Type startupModuleType, PlugInSourceList plugInSources)
   at Volo.Abp.Modularity.ModuleLoader.GetDescriptors(IServiceCollection services, Type startupModuleType, PlugInSourceList plugInSources)
   at Volo.Abp.Modularity.ModuleLoader.LoadModules(IServiceCollection services, Type startupModuleType, PlugInSourceList plugInSources)
   at Volo.Abp.AbpApplicationBase..ctor(Type startupModuleType, IServiceCollection services, Action`1 optionsAction)
   at Volo.Abp.AbpApplicationFactory.CreateAsync[TStartupModule](IServiceCollection services, Action`1 optionsAction)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionApplicationExtensions.AddApplicationAsync[TStartupModule](IServiceCollection services, Action`1 optionsAction)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.WebApplicationBuilderExtensions.AddApplicationAsync[TStartupModule](WebApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 optionsAction)
   at DCC.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

although all projects are the same version 5.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in version of packages when you replace packages with code the version of resulted Dll will be different than the other Abp packages
So what you should do is to set the version in csproj for each project in your module
in your case set version to 5.3.0